# How to implement handwriting recognition feature in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, handwriting

I have a requirement in my iPhone app which is something similar to **Handwriting Recognition**.

I want to give user a space on my view where he can write any character by touch and dragging his finger on the screen and based on what matches with his input the textbox should show the English alphabet.

Above is an example of what I want:

[image]

How should I implement this feature? I am a beginner in this.

Comment: If you came up with a good answer for this, you'd probably get some honorary Ph.Ds from several major universities.

Comment: @Dave DeLong : why so? Is it something not available yet?

Comment: because it's an extremely difficult problem. Everyone has different styles of handwriting, different ways/orders of drawing different characters; some characters (like `f`) require multiple strokes (maybe, if that's how you learned it); If this were an easy problem, it would've been solved long ago.

Comment: ok thanks for your input Dave DeLong :) I am glad that you gave me the information and answered politely to my silly question :) Thanks!!

Comment: For a better explanation, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handwriting_recognition

Comment: @ParthBhatt: Found any solution Bro ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no handwriting Frameworks or Libraries currently available. If you are brainy enough use some gesture techniques of iOS and handwriting algorithms to create it

Comment: Hey I like when you said " If you are brainy enough". Thanks that you gave me the information that there is no frameworks currently available in iPhone SDK that can help me achieve what I intend to. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You better start to learn about image processing for this feature. It is not difficult but the  OCR , should be your similar coding. However, because of its transient then the hand writing recognition is much difficult.. But anyway, it is doable.

Comment: Being a newbie at handwriting recognition is not really a question either.  You are talking about the combined sum effort of decades of research.  This is not an appropriate question for SO.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some code around to subclass UIGestureRecognizer to define a "check" gesture. It recognizes touch beginning, moving southeast, then moving northeast to draw a checkmark. Perhaps you could define letter shapes as specific gesture recognizers and then attached your whole alphabet of recognizers to a view and see what you get.